# How do I cross compile the Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation

I've spent hours, if not days figuring out how to cross compile Linux for AArch64.

I'm using Ubuntu in a VM to do this, however all guides I managed to find didn't work completely. Most of them assumed the end-user had Debian, and things are named differently there. Once I was able to get a configuration profile to be made, but I couldn't get it to be used. when I typed in `make`, I got a questionnaire for x86-based systems, despite I've saved the config file with menuconfig. Then I specified the `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` parameters, then I get yet another questionnaire, with skipping a lot of things that would've been essential for my build target.

Then my Ubuntu VM needed to be reinstalled, so I'm back at almost square zero, with no idea what I needed to install to get the cross-compilation to work, or how I did specify the `CROSS_COMPILE` parameter. I've installed the compiler (took hours to figure out how it's called under Ubuntu), but it has a different name when needed to be specified for cross-compilation. Maybe I've skipped something.

Yes, I've googled it multiple times, and most guides assumed the user knew a lot of quite obscure stuff. Many of them were even more than a decade old.

Answer (score 6):

To cross-compile a kernel for AArch64 on Ubuntu, you need to install `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu`, and run the build as

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- ...
```

Thus

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- menuconfig
```

to configure, and

```
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- all
```

to build the kernel and modules.

If you can’t find an option you’re expecting, use <kbd>/</kbd> in `menuconfig` to look for it; that will tell you what else needs to be enabled.

(These are the same instructions as for Debian; the core cross-compiler packages are named the same in Debian and Ubuntu nowadays.)